# Mongoid, complex query, something similar to has_many : through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following models:

```
class Company
  # ...
  has_many :invoices
end

class Invoice
  # ...
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :items

  field :type, String

  scope :expense, where(type: 'expense')
  scope :income, where(type: 'income')
end

class Item
  # ...
  belongs_to :invoice
end
```

The question is how to fetch all `income` Items for the given company?

Something similar to `company.items.expense`

Answer (score -1):

Using embedded relations won't make any difference. Calling `company.items.expense` would still return an error, since `company.items` returns an Array.

Try something like this:

```
class Company
  #...
  def expenses
     self.invoices.where(type: 'expense')
  end

  def incomes
     self.invoices.where(type: 'income')
  end
end
```

Then you can call `company.expenses` and `company.incomes`.

Depending on your usage, you may find it better to embed `Item` inside `Invoice` or leave it as a separate collection. Also, since you're dealing with invoices, remember to be careful with your callbacks and make them cascade where necessary, so `Invoice` modified time changes if an `Item` gets changed.